# Video file not running on browser

Tags: android, html5-video, android-video-player

In android i have created .mp4 video file and stored it in sdcard. From sdcard i have copied it into computer and try to run it on browser using video tag.

My html code is:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
  <source src="12.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="12.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

</body>
</html>
```

And my android code is:-

```
private MediaRecorder prMediaRecorder;
prMediaRecorder.setCamera(prCamera);
prMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
prMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
prMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
prMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(VideoEncoder.H264);
```

Comment: what ?? you are trying to play or trying to record ???

Comment: i have record video by using android phone then stored it in sdcard. After from sdcard i copied it into my computer and try to run it on browser.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
  <source src="12.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="12.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

</body>
</html>
```

Try putting direct path to the video?

```
 private MediaRecorder prMediaRecorder;
prMediaRecorder.setCamera(prCamera);
prMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
prMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
prMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
prMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(VideoEncoder.H264);
```

Aren't this code for Camera? I am not quite sure regarding this android code but it seems like a android camera code